# Initiate Facebook "Like" in an email

Tags: facebook, email

I'm trying to use a custom image that when clicked initiates a Facebook "Like" to our business Facebook page. This would be in an email template.

Sounds simple but this has proved impossible to do. Any articles I could find were years old and didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no way.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why?

Comment: Certainly there is no way for clicking an image to cause someone to like your page (facebook would not allow this, to prevent abuse). I don't know if there's a way to bring up a Facebook page where the user is asked whether they want to like your page or not.